# Where are the MTG Lexicon pages?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I fail to find more recent than 2005 MTG Lexicon pages in the Archives

Those are the ones I already have:

- https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/lexicon-archive-2002-01-15
- https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/lexicon-2003-09-04
- https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/lexicon-throwback-edition-2004-11-30
- https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/lexicon-ravnica-edition-2005-10-05

Are there more recent pages published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, collect the Google results of [site:magic.wizards.com inurl:lexicon](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:magic.wizards.com+inurl:lexicon).

Then, check the longer results of [site:magic.wizards.com lexicon](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:magic.wizards.com+lexicon).

Comment: If you add date restricts to those queries you can see that there haven't been any published at all recently. The dates Google has aren't all exactly right, though, probably because Wizards has redone the site and republished things on later dates. At the very least, it was [long since retired by 2012](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/turning-ten-2012-01-02).

Comment: Strange that there are no new lexicon articles since 7 Feb 2013. https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/gatecrash-lexicon-2013-02-07